# Regex pattern doesn't work with MySQL regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-like

I do have the below regex that works fine with Regex tester (thanks to [horcrux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4607733/horcrux)). However, it returns no matches when I use it with MySQL regexp

```
select query from search s where s.query regexp '^((&|^)(serviceType=SALE|propertyType=HOUSE|city=1)){1,3}$'
```

The above should match the below

```
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1
propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1
city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE
city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=SALE
```

but not these

```
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=2
propertyType=HOUSE&city=2&serviceType=SALE
city=2&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=FARM&city=1
serviceType=SALE&propertyType=UNIT
serviceType=RENTAL&propertyType=HOUSE
serviceType=RENTAL
```

Comment: Does `^(serviceType=SALE|propertyType=HOUSE|city=1)(&(serviceType=SALE|propertyType=HOUSE|city=1)){0,2}$` work? What is the error? Is there any?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a2d887c9a7e493ade8f6443ba035fe5

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It works in the tester but still no matches in MySQL regexp unfortunately

Comment: Works with MySQL 5.7 too: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CYKKJ2gs1EUQ57vo1Gmyu/0

Comment: @zoro74 both links I have posted are using MySQL...

Comment: Thanks @nick it actually works now when I used a query to insert test values to the table. Originally I copy/pasted values directly to the search table which seems to have caused the issue. Thanks again to the quick reply

Comment: @zoro74 maybe you accidentally got some whitespace in the values when you were testing. Anyway, good to hear it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you rather want the string to match all of the key value pairs not just any, which is what you current pattern matches.

Try `AND`ing the `REGEXP` operations, one for each key value pair.

```
s.query REGEXP '(&|^)serviceType=SALE(&|$)'
        AND s.query REGEXP '(&|^)propertyType=HOUSE(&|$)'
        AND s.query REGEXP '(&|^)city=1(&|$)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard workaround without using regex, this post is just meant to show it's possible.  
The trick is to make a MySQL number generator and use nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions to cut the strings up into tokens.

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
   separated_key_values.query
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           separated_key_values.separated_property
         , '='
         , 1
       )
      ,'='
     , -1
   ) AS property_key
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           separated_key_values.separated_property
         , '='
         , 2
       )
      ,'='
     , -1
   ) AS property_value   
FROM (

SELECT 
  DISTINCT
     search.query 
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           search.query
         , '&'
         , number_generator.row_number
       )
      ,'&'
     , -1
   ) separated_property
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS row_number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2  
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN 
 search 

) AS separated_key_values
ORDER BY 
 separated_key_values.query ASC
```

**Result**

```
| query                                      | property_key | property_value |
| ------------------------------------------ | ------------ | -------------- |
| city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | city         | 1              |
| city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | serviceType  | SALE           |
| city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE | city         | 1              |
| city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE | serviceType  | SALE           |
| city=2&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | serviceType  | SALE           |
| city=2&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | city         | 2              |
| city=2&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| propertyType=HOUSE&city=2&serviceType=SALE | city         | 2              |
| propertyType=HOUSE&city=2&serviceType=SALE | serviceType  | SALE           |
| propertyType=HOUSE&city=2&serviceType=SALE | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1 | city         | 1              |
| propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1 | serviceType  | SALE           |
| propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1 | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| serviceType=RENTAL                         | serviceType  | RENTAL         |
| serviceType=RENTAL&propertyType=HOUSE      | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| serviceType=RENTAL&propertyType=HOUSE      | serviceType  | RENTAL         |
| serviceType=SALE                           | serviceType  | SALE           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=FARM&city=1  | serviceType  | SALE           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=FARM&city=1  | propertyType | FARM           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=FARM&city=1  | city         | 1              |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE        | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE        | serviceType  | SALE           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1 | city         | 1              |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1 | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1 | serviceType  | SALE           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=2 | propertyType | HOUSE          |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=2 | city         | 2              |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=2 | serviceType  | SALE           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=UNIT         | propertyType | UNIT           |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=UNIT         | serviceType  | SALE           |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/66uENeks24Tao7jSpLXKg8/2)

After that it just as simple as adding as conditional aggregation.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  separated_key_values.query

, 

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'serviceType') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = 'SALE') > 0

 ) AS has_serviceType_SALE

, 

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'propertyType') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = 'HOUSE') > 0

 ) AS has_propertyType_HOUSE

, 

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'City') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = '1') > 0

 )  AS has_City_1

, (

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'serviceType') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = 'SALE') > 0

 ) 

 + 

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'propertyType') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = 'HOUSE') > 0

 ) 

 + 

 (
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_key = 'City') > 0
 AND
   SUM(separated_key_values.property_value = '1') > 0

 )   

  ) AS has_mask 

, COUNT(*)

FROM (
SELECT 
   search_alias.query
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           search_alias.separated_property
         , '='
         , 1
       )
      ,'='
     , -1
   ) AS property_key
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           search_alias.separated_property
         , '='
         , 2
       )
      ,'='
     , -1
   ) AS property_value   
FROM (

SELECT 
  DISTINCT
     search.query 
   , SUBSTRING_INDEX(
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           search.query
         , '&'
         , number_generator.row_number
       )
      ,'&'
     , -1
   ) separated_property
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS row_number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2  
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN 
 search 

) AS search_alias
) AS separated_key_values
GROUP BY 
 separated_key_values.query
HAVING 
 has_mask = COUNT(*)
```

**Result**

```
| query                                      | has_serviceType_SALE | has_propertyType_HOUSE | has_City_1 | has_mask | COUNT(*) |
| ------------------------------------------ | -------------------- | ---------------------- | ---------- | -------- | -------- |
| city=1&propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE | 1                    | 1                      | 1          | 3        | 3        |
| city=1&serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE | 1                    | 1                      | 1          | 3        | 3        |
| propertyType=HOUSE&serviceType=SALE&city=1 | 1                    | 1                      | 1          | 3        | 3        |
| serviceType=SALE                           | 1                    | 0                      | 0          | 1        | 1        |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE        | 1                    | 1                      | 0          | 2        | 2        |
| serviceType=SALE&propertyType=HOUSE&city=1 | 1                    | 1                      | 1          | 3        | 3        |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/66uENeks24Tao7jSpLXKg8/3)

You could also place the column output into the `HAVING` clause so you don't output those columns. 
 See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/66uENeks24Tao7jSpLXKg8/4)

**Note** 
 
This will not scale on large tables most likely the regex query will also not scale because indexes most likely can't be used.

A workaround method might be to use a temporary table with a correct index and use the first query to prefill and do the conditional aggregation on the temporary table which is indexed.